# Viewing files and folders in Google Drive

Tags: usability, user-expectation, user-centered-design, google

Google drive has a grid view option with which the files are listed as tiles/cards and the folders are represented in a small rectangular box at the top. Why is that approach and is there any other variant for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile first
http://www.themobileplaybook.com/en-us/

Google have been instructed to think first about mobile and fit everything else (e.g desktop) in afterwards.

Folders don't need to be big tiles and on a mobile, if they were, they would take up valuable space.
So, for consistency, and with a mobile-first view-point, they should be smaller than the files. Seeing an image of a file will help you quickly determine which one it is (and makes the app feel nicer) so preferable over just text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variant implemented: you can switch to a list view in the horizontal Google Drive menu. 
[image]

Comment: The options are fine. But in the GRID layout, the view for folders is not similar to that of files. THe folders could have been made as tiles. But they 've gone for a strip which doesn't get much attracted when there are more files than the number of folders in that level